# Authentication with Spring oAuth2.0

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, oauth-2.0

I want to authenticate users on my website by facebook/twitter accounts. But in spring examples, spring ask me to login first, and only after that, when user already has a role, I can connect to facebook and get some data. Even if there are no permissions at facebookData controller (`intercept-url pattern="/**" access="permitAll"`) spring redirects me to the login page.

- Does it mean, that OpenAuth can't be used for authentication
  anonymouse user?

My spring-security:

```
    <http use-expressions="true">
        <form-login login-page="/login" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="permitAll" />
        <logout />
        <custom-filter ref="oauth2ClientFilter" after="EXCEPTION_TRANSLATION_FILTER" />
    </http>
    <oauth:client id="oauth2ClientFilter" />

<oauth:resource id="facebook" type="authorization_code" client-id="..." client-secret="..." authentication-scheme="query"
    access-token-uri="https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token" user-authorization-uri="https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth" token-name="oauth_token" client-authentication-scheme="form" scope="email"/>

<bean id="facebookController" class="org.springframework.security.oauth.examples.tonr.mvc.FacebookController" />

<oauth:rest-template resource="facebook" id="fasebookRestTemplate">
    <property name="messageConverters">
        <list>
            <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter">
                <property name="supportedMediaTypes">
                    <list>
                        <bean class="org.springframework.http.MediaType">
                            <!--facebook sends its json as text/javascript for some reason -->
                            <constructor-arg value="text" />
                            <constructor-arg value="javascript" />
                        </bean>
                        <bean class="org.springframework.http.MediaType">
                            <constructor-arg value="application" />
                            <constructor-arg value="json" />
                        </bean>
                    </list>
                </property>
            </bean>
        </list>
    </property>
</oauth:rest-template>
```

And facebook controller:

```
@Autowired
private RestOperations facebookRestTemplate;

@RequestMapping("/facebook/info")
public String photos(Model model) throws Exception {

    ObjectNode resultNode = facebookRestTemplate.getForObject("https://graph.facebook.com/me/friends", ObjectNode.class);
    ArrayNode data = (ArrayNode) resultNode.get("data");
    ArrayList<String> friends = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (JsonNode dataNode : data) {
        friends.add(dataNode.get("name").getTextValue());
    }
    model.addAttribute("friends", friends);
    return "facebook";
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a cool library that does exactly this: https://github.com/socialsignin/spring-social-security

I have successfully made use of it - where all the user has to do is connect to Facebook to get authenticated. To create a new user upon the very first connect, you simply extend `SpringSocialSecurityConnectionSignUp`, overriding the `execute` method. The Github page explains nicely what you need to do. It also has some sample projects which are really useful as well.

The project is in Maven. Have fun!

Comment: Thank you, but I plan to connect not only facebook and twitter, any way I found answer here http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/security/oauth/121682-authentication-is-required-to-obtain-an-access-token-anonymous-not-allowed